# Вк-бот отвечает в ЛС, но не отвечает в беседах, что делать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Написал коротенького бота для тестирования функций. Загвоздка в том, что он отвечает только в сообщениях группы, но не в чаты. Не могу найти причину, не появляется никакой ошибки.

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import vk_api
from datetime import datetime
import time


def write_msg(user_id, random_id, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, "random_id": 
random_id, 'message': message})


token = "тут мой токен"
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        if event.from_user:
            write_msg(event.user_id, event.random_id, "первая фраза")
        elif event.from_chat:
            write_msg(event.сhat_id, event.random_id, "вторая фраза")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `write_msg(event.сhat_id, event.random_id, "вторая фраза")` - это строчка не выполняеться да?

Comment: @Melis да, именно она. Хоть убей, не могу понять, почему

Comment: продебаж код, останови интерпретатор на строчке `if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:` походу условие `event.to_me` не работает для груп. чатов

Comment: @Melis Дебаг подсказал мне, что проблема вообще не в этом. longpoll.listen() не считает сообщение в чатах event'ом, просто не видит его даже. Че делать?

Comment: откуда токен? из группы? может есть что-то в настройке группы? вроде должно быть "разраешить добавлять бота в группу"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Бот должен быть добавлен в беседу (Для этого необходимо включить `Возможности ботов` (`Управление->Сообщения->Настройки для бота`) и разрешить добавлять его в беседы (там же)).
2. Для использования `Long Poll` необходимо включить `Long Poll Api` (`Управление->Настройки->Работа с API->Long Poll API`) и указать, какие события Вы хотите ловить (`Типы событий`).
3. Для бота-сообщества следует использовать `vk_api.bot_longpoll`.
4. Чтобы бот увидел сообщение, его необходимо упомянуть (например, @club666666), либо администратор беседы должен дать ему полный доступ к переписке.

Советую посмотреть: [Получаю ошибку при попытке отправки сообщения в беседу через VK_API Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955511/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-vk-api-python)

Вчера сам столкнулся с такой проблемой, сегодня описал решение: [VkBotLongPoll игнорирует сообщения из беседы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955612/vkbotlongpoll-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B)

Comment: Мало где можно нарыть инфу про VkBotLongPoll, лично я вообще нигде, ни на хабре, ни на гите, подобного не нашел. Большое спасибо! Не желаете залить свою находку на хабр? Устаревшие статьи мало полезного дают читающим, это будет лучше всего, что там есть на эту тему касательно питона.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное вы забыли поставить галочку "Разрешать добавлять сообщество в беседы" раз даже  longpoll.listen() не обрабатываеться
Это настройка лежить в Настройки группы -> Сообщения -> Настройки для бота
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]