# Получаю ошибку при попытке отправки сообщения в беседу через VK_API Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, python-3.5, бот

Играюсь с ботостроением и решил отправить сообщение в беседу, делаю такой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

def main():
        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='ТОКЕН')
        vk = vk_session.get_api()
        longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'ИД ГРУППЫ')

        for event in longpoll.listen():

                if event.obj.text == '[clubСКРЫТО|*СКРЫТО] ответь':
                    vk.messages.send(
                        random_id=get_random_id(),
                        chat_id = 111,
                        #peer_id = 2000000111,
                        message='Heh'
                        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Но на выходе получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./2pb.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "./2pb.py", line 20, in main
    message='Heh'
  File "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vk_api/vk_api.py", line 671, in __call__
    return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
  File "/home/boss/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vk_api/vk_api.py", line 636, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [10] Internal server error
```

Назначал группу администратором беседы, давал доступ к переписке полный, пробовал отправлять вместе с `peer_id`, пробовал без `chat_id` - результат один и тот же.

Ключ сгенерирован на полный доступ.

В чем проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Всё ещё не работает? https://vk.com/dev/errors

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, теперь вообще не работает xD | https://github.com/python273/vk_api/issues/234

Comment: Попробуйте в методе `messages.send` указать `peer_id = event.obj.peer_id`. В моём коде это единственное отличие от вашего, у меня прекрасно работает.
Источники, которые я смотрел для решения Вашей проблемы: https://vk.com/dev/messages.send https://habr.com/ru/post/428507/ https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/vk_api/bot_longpoll.py https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vk_api.html

Comment: Нет. Я вам наврал. Сообщения из бесед он у меня игнорирует. Теперь интересно, почему?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, получается у нас у обоих всё сломалось... Случай смешной, ситуация досадная(. Кст, чтобы бот видел сообщение, его надо упомянуть. Или дать полный доступ к переписке.

Comment: Кст, а `peer_id = event.obj.peer_id` работает :D

Comment: Что значит "Дать полный доступ к переписке"?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов а там в беседе, на выпадающем меню где можно админом назначить. У сообществ там ещё будет `Дать полный доступ к переписке`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: в методе `messages.send` получателя указать, как `peer_id = event.obj.peer_id`

```
vk.messages.send(
    random_id   =   get_random_id(),
    peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
    message     =   'Heh'
    )
```

В таком случае бот будет отвечать, если: 1 - ему написали в личку, 2 - его упомянули в беседе. По хорошему ещё стоит проверять, что за событие мы ловим из `longpoll.listen()`:

```
if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
    vk.messages.send(
        random_id   =   get_random_id(),
        peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
        message     =   'Heh'
        )
```