# 10 Internal server error

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Решил вот создать бота для бесед ВК. Добавил его в одну беседу, начал пытаться через него начать что-то писать и тут ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 11, in <module>
    msg(2000000000+50, 'проверка')
  File "bot.py", line 9, in msg
    vk.messages.send(peer_id=idd, random_id=0, message=text)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 671, in __call__
    return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 636, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [10] Internal server error
```

Вот кстати сам код:

```
import vk_api

token = 'СКРЫТО'

session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = session.get_api()

def msg(idd, text):
    vk.messages.send(peer_id=idd, random_id=0, message=text)

msg(2000000000+50, 'проверка')
```

Подскажите что не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь отправить сообщение в несуществующий диалог. Такая проблема была [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955511/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-vk-api-python/956047#956047). Вы хотите писать в беседу под номером 50, но под номером 50 она находится у **вас** на странице, у **бота** у неё наверняка другой номер (догадываюсь, что 1). Плюсом в качестве `random_id` можете передавать `random.getrandbits(32)`. Лучше сразу использовать `vk_api` в связке с Long Poll. Советую ознакомиться со следующими вопросами: [VkBotLongPoll игнорирует сообщения из беседы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955612/vkbotlongpoll-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B/956359#956359) [Вк-бот отвечает в ЛС, но не отвечает в беседах, что делать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954736/%D0%92%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%9B%D0%A1-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/956264#956264) [Получаю ошибку при попытке отправки сообщения в беседу через VK_API Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955511/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-vk-api-python/956047#956047)

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогло!