# VkBotLongPoll игнорирует сообщения из беседы

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Попробовал написать чат-бота для вк, используя LongPoll. В чём проблема: на личные сообщения он реагирует, а сообщения из конференции игнорирует. Код:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import random

def main():
    replies = [ "ответ1", "ответ2", "ответ3" ]
    bot_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="Токен сообщества-бота, доступ ко всему")
    bot_api = bot_session.get_api()
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(bot_session, "id сообщества-бота")
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        print("got event")
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print("message")
            bot_api.messages.send(
                random_id   =   random.getrandbits(32),
                peer_id     =   event.obj.peer_id,
                message     =   random.choice(replies)
                )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

При написании сообщений в беседе в консоли даже не появляется "got event". В настройках LongPoll сервера указано реагирование *только* на входящие сообщения и добавления записей на стену.

Comment: Мне кажется это по вашей проблеме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/954736/201445

Comment: @gil9red Я там сам уже ответил с отсылкой на этот вопрос :) Чуть позже напишу развернутый ответ тут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: Бота необходимо было упомянуть (например, `@club66666 Эй ты`), либо администратор беседы должен дать ему полный доступ к переписке. Также добавлю, что слушание Long Poll сервера следует обернуть в `try except`, ибо в случае простоя он валится и бросает исключение таймаута. В коде это выглядит так:

```
import requests

bot_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="Токен сообщества-бота, доступ ко всему")
bot_api = bot_session.get_api()
while True:
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(bot_session, "id сообщества-бота")
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            #...
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout as timeout:
        continue
```

Comment: Откуда Вы доставали id группы? Я запускаю Ваш код и получаю следующее: Traceback (most recent call last): File "tt.py", line 21, in <module> main() File "tt.py", line 9, in main longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(bot_session, "id") File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vk_api/bot_longpoll.py", line 207, in __init__ self.update_longpoll_server() File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vk_api/bot_longpoll.py", line 220, in update_longpoll_server response = self.vk.method('groups.getLongPollServer', values) File "/Lib

Comment: @RostVel Способов узнать id сообщества очень много, гуглите.