# Бот в вк сообщества не видит сообщения в беседе

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Задача: Бот, который отвечает в беседе на сообщения

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
vk_session= vk_api.VkApi(token=*token*)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat
        vk_session.method('messages.send',{'peer_id':2000000001, "chat_id":1,'random_id':0, 'message':"Проверка"})
```

Именно так не работает и не отправляет сообщения вообще. Пробовал по-разному `event.from_chat` - не получается

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.text and event.to_me:
    vk_session.method('messages.send',{'peer_id':2000000001, "chat_id":1,'random_id':0, 'message':"Проверка"})
```

Сделал так, то он отправляет сообщения в беседу только тогда, когда я напишу боту в лс

Можете помочь:

Как правильно написать код, чтобы бот ЧИТАЛ и ОТВЕЧАЛ на сообщения В БЕСЕДЕ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [VkBotLongPoll игнорирует сообщения из беседы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955612/vkbotlongpoll-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Это из-за `VkLongPoll`.

В [документации](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/longpoll.html) указано, что это модуль для пользователей.
Так как Вы авторизуетесь с ключом сообщества, Вам требуется `VkBotLongPoll`.

Обратите внимание на то, что он находится в другом модуле, а именно в `vk_api.bot_longpoll`

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


vk_session = VkApi(token='[access_token]')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '[group_id]')
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
            vk.messages.send(
                random_id=get_random_id(),
                peer_id=event.obj['peer_id'],
                message='Test message',
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: @Huskey Вы права на чтение переписки боту выдали? Или упомянули его?

Comment: Да, выдал. Но он все равно не хочет

Comment: @Huskey Вы заменили в моём коде `[access_token]` и `[group_id]` на свои значения?

Comment: Да, я заменил все, что требовалось, но ничего не вышло

Comment: @Huskey Что именно происходит? Возникает какая-то ошибка?

Comment: В беседе он не видит сообщения. Но как только начинаю писать ему в личные сообщения, то выдает ```if self.obj.peer_id < 0:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' ```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98631/discussion-between-nomnoms12-and-huskey).