# Бот ВК не видит сообщений из беседы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал бота для группы ВК, в сообщениях всё работает, но когда добавляю его в беседу, то он не видит сообщений. Прикрепляю код бота, подскажите как исправить

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
import vk_api
import random
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse, json, random, time, datetime

token = "Токен Группы"
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def create_keyboard(response):
    keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=False)

    if response == "Открыть":

        keyboard.add_button("Команды", color=VkKeyboardColor.DEFAULT)
        keyboard.add_button("Закрыть", color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

        keyboard.add_line()
        keyboard.add_button("2", color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)

        keyboard.add_line()
        keyboard.add_button("3", color=VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
        keyboard.add_button("4", color=VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)

    elif response == "закрыть":
        print("Закрываемся")
        return keyboard.get_keyboard()
    keyboard = keyboard.get_keyboard()
    return keyboard



while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print("Текст Сообщения: " + str(event.text))
            print(event.user_id)
            response = event.text.lower()
            keyboard = create_keyboard(response)

            if event.from_user and not (event.from_me):
                if response == "привет":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "Приветики", "random_id": 0})
                elif response == "как дела?":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "Всё супер, твои как?", "random_id": 0})
                elif response == "команды":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "1. Реклама\n2. Аниме\n3. Админы", "keyboard" : keyboard, "random_id": 0})
                elif response == "реклама":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "По всем вопросам рекламы обращайтесь к  (Админу)", "random_id": 0})
                elif response == "нормально":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "Я рада что у вас всё Хорошо:)","random_id": 0})
                elif response == "хорошо":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "Я рада что у вас всё Хорошо:)","random_id": 0})
                elif response == "плохо":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "О нет, что случилось?\n(Если вам нужна помощь или поддержка, обратитесь к Глав.Админу по команде Админы)","random_id": 0})
                elif response == "админы":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": " (Глав.Админ)\n (Зам.Админ)\n (Беларусский Мафиози)","random_id": 0})
                elif response == "аниме":
                   a = open("anime.txt").readlines()
                   vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": (random.choice(a)), "random_id": 0})
                else:
                    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id": event.user_id, "message": "Я не понимать что вы пытаться мне сказать", "random_id": 0})


            elif event.from_chat:
                if response == "йокки привет":
                    vk_session.method("messages.send",{"chat_id": event.chat_id, "message": "Приветики", "random_id": 0})
```

Comment: Зачем Вы используете Longpoll пользователя при работе с сообществом?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [VkBotLongPoll игнорирует сообщения из беседы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/955612/vkbotlongpoll-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Comment: Возможно это бы решило мою проблему, но я новенький в программировании,а что бы использовать ваш метод мне нужно переписывать полностью код, но к сожалению я не знаю как именно

Comment: Заменить все `VkLongPoll` и `VkEventType` на `VkBotLongPoll` и `VkBotEventType` и всё...

Comment: Вместо `user_id` и `chat_id` можно использовать универсальный `peer_id`.

Comment: И из-за `"random_id": 0` сообщения могут попросту не отправляться.

Comment: Тогда вылазят ошибки cвязанные с атрибутами

Comment: *>>вылазят ошибки cвязанные с атрибутами* - абсолютно бесполезное сообщение. Сразу прилагайте их, почему это из Вас вытягивать приходится?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/STASYUK/PycharmProjects/Бот YokkiChan/Бот.py", line 42, in <module>
    print("Текст Сообщения: " + str(event.text))
AttributeError: 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Посмотрите пример из комментариев под ответом @moragame, там показано, как указывать `group_id` и как обратиться к тексту сообщения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, попробуйте указать `group_id` вашей группы и используйте `vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll`.

```py
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id=0) # вместо 0 - ваш текущий id группы
```

---

Попробовал переписать.

```py
import vk_api
import vk_api.bot_longpoll
import vk_api.keyboard

import random

session = vk_api.VkApi(token='token')
api = session.get_api()
longpoll = vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll(session, group_id=0)

def create_keyboard():
    keyboard = vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboard(one_time=False)

    keyboard.add_button("Команды", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.DEFAULT)
    keyboard.add_button("Закрыть", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)

    keyboard.add_line()
    keyboard.add_button("2", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)

    keyboard.add_line()
    keyboard.add_button("3", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)
    keyboard.add_button("4", color=vk_api.keyboard.VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY)

    return keyboard.get_keyboard()


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        response = event.obj.text or event.message.text # не уверен насчёт event.message.text

        keyboard = create_keyboard()

        if event.from_user:
            if response == "привет":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="Приветики", random_id=0)
            elif response == "как дела?":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="Всё супер, твои как?", random_id=0)
            elif response == "команды":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="1. Реклама\n2. Аниме\n3. Админы", keyboard=keyboard, random_id=0)
            elif response == "реклама":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="По всем вопросам рекламы обращайтесь к  (Админу)", random_id=0)
            elif response == "нормально":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="Я рада что у вас всё Хорошо:)", random_id=0)
            elif response == "хорошо":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="Я рада что у вас всё Хорошо:)", random_id=0)
            elif response == "плохо":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="О нет, что случилось?\n(Если вам нужна помощь или поддержка, обратитесь к Глав.Админу по команде Админы)", random_id=0)
            elif response == "админы":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message=" (Глав.Админ)\n (Зам.Админ)\n (Беларусский Мафиози)", random_id=0)
            elif response == "аниме":
                a = open("anime.txt").readlines()
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message=random.choice(a), random_id=0)
            else:
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="Я не понимать что вы пытаться мне сказать", random_id=0)
        elif event.from_chat:
            if response == "йокки привет":
                api.messages.send(chat_id= event.chat_id, message="Приветики", random_id=0)
```

Comment: Всё то же самое, не видит сообщений в добавленных беседах

Comment: 1. Точно ли тот `group_id`? 2. Попробуйте `vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll` 3. Попробуйте [пример](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/bot_longpoll.py)

Comment: Групп айди точно тот, возможно VkBotLongPoll поможет, но мне нужно переписывать весь код под него, но мне навыков не хватает:)

Comment: Мне кажется, что нужен `VkBotLongPoll`. Сейчас разберу исходники, почитаю. Как записываете `group_id`? Он должен быть целым числом.

Comment: longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session, group_id=126169390)

Comment: Проверил `vk_api.bot_longpoll.VkBotLongPoll` и `vk_api.longpoll.VkLongPoll` (`python 3.7.3`, `vk_api==11.6.1`). Работает только `bot_longpoll`. Также в исходниках видно, что стоят разные литералы методов получения longpoll серверов. Предполагаю (но не гарантирую), что `VkLongPoll` не поддерживает сообщения из чатов, но могу ошибаться.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, тогда займусь переписью кода

Comment: Попробовал адаптировать ваш код под `bot_longpoll`.

Comment: Да я видел, всё заработало, огромное вам спасибо, вы меня выручили, сам бы я дня 2 бы потратил что бы переписать код